# Add leading 0 if x < 10 and store it as an int

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small "Time" functions library just to learn more about how to work with C++ and functions in general.

I'm having a function that is called `Time(int hh, int mm, int sec)`

I want if the user enters `Time(11, 9, 14)` 
I want to store this values in memory as `hh = 11; mm = 09; sec = 14;` to be used later on.

I know that if I were to use a `cout` I could have used `cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << mm << endl;`

But now I want to directly store the value as an int, how do I do this?`

I tried `time = (tt > 10) ? 0 + mm : mm;` But i guess this is just like doing basic addition 0+9 = 9.

Comment: Yes, it's doing basic addition. The int is not stored as a string in memory and doesn't know anything about leading zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't.

**A number is a number.**

You are storing the value "nine". This can be written as a decimal literal `9`, or an octal literal `010`, or a hex literal `0x09`, or a hex literal `0x0000000009`, or the English "nine", or the French "neuf"…

…or as the formatted, zero-padded string `"09"` which is possible in C++ but utterly pointless as you sacrifice direct access to arithmetic, lose value validation, and now have to convert it back to a number to do anything interesting with it.

The value you're looking for is already there (actually internally stored as as sequence of binary bits). The information "zero-pad it to two decimal digits" is not part of the value, but part of a possible *representation* on screen.

Just store `9` in your `int` and format it when you want to output it.

Comment: ... unless it's a float or a double or a bignum (but that is probably a lesson for the future)

Comment: @MartinBonner Still the case that value and display form are two separate things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, That's a nice explanation on why I should not do it like I thought, appreciate the pointers! Thanks.

Comment: @PetterÖstergren Have some more! `0xDEADBEEF` `0xCCCCCCCC` `0x404`