# How can I toggle N-bit of integer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, toggle, bit

I try to toggle the bits of a numeric value by using the `~` complement operator, but it results in a negative number. For example I want toggle `5 -> 2 (101 -> 010)`

How can I change this number in **Visual Studio**?

Comment: "it is '-' number" do you mean it is a signed number?

Comment: You want to ignore leading `0` (as `5` is at `0b00000101`)? or fixed size ? (so `2` (`0b010`) -> `1` (`0b001`) or `5` (`0b101`)).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the XOR operator `^`.

If your original number is `x`, then:

```
int y = x ^ 0b111;
```

Will have the first 3 bits flipped (I supposed that's what you meant by "toggled").

Answer (score 0):

As a 32-bit value, 5 is not 0b101. It is 0b0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0101.

(Although [those leading zeroes are not significant, value-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965711/560648), the fact that you are performing bit operations makes the "width" of the binary representation important.)

So, when you flip all the bits, you get 0b1111'1111'1111'1111'1111'1111'1111'1010 which is indeed a negative number per two's complement encoding.

If you just wanted to flip the three least significant bits, you can use a mask to do that:

```
const int y = x ^ 0b111;
```

This will leave all the other bits alone.

Comment: @Jarod42 Haha I'm always doing that

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this:

```
number ^= 1UL << N
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I solve this problem.

By Use `number ^= 1UL << N`  Thank you for your Answer.

Answer (score -2):

Hello you can do like this .

(~N)<0 ? (long)pow(2, 32) + ~N : ~N;

Comment: Let me know what is the problem with this code to deserve a negative vote , this will help me improve .